# Is $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\log i}{(i^2+1)^{1/2}}$ convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Initial thought was that $\log n < n$ so by comparison series is less that $ \sum i/(i+1)^{1/2}$ but that is inconclusive from ratio test.

Comment: Presumable, that should be $(n^2+1)^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the sum at $i=2$. Then compare to $\sum\frac1i$, using $$\log i > 1/2$$ (or some other small constant) and $$i^2+1<4i^2$$ (the coefficient $4$ is for tidiness).

Answer (score 0):

$ln(n)/\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is a sequence of positive numbers that do not increase.  So Cauchy's theorem on convergence is germane. Notice that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^k ln(2^k)}{\sqrt{(2^{k})^2+1}}= ln(2)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k 2^k} {\sqrt{(2^{k})^2+1}}
>
ln(2)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k 2^k} {\sqrt{(2^{k})^2+(2^{k})^2}}
$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^k ln(2^k)}{\sqrt{(2^{k})^2+1}} 
>
\dfrac{ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k 2^k} {\sqrt{(2^{k})^2}}
=
\dfrac{ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k$$
and that sum surely diverges.